# How to serve static file using Restify

Tags: node.js, file, static, restify

I am working with a node application, where I need to serve static files(js,css).

My project structure is like below:

```
-Projectroot
     -restifyServer
         -server.js
     -frontEnd
         -index.html
         -js
         -partials
         -css
```

server.js is not only the server it serves XML also.

Also for serving index.html I have routing like below:

```
server.get('/', getIndexhtml);
```

And getIndexhtml callback is like:

```
var getIndexhtml = function indexHTML(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../frontendapp/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
        next();
});
}
```

When I start server and navigate my browser to '`http://localhost:8080/`' it loads html without static files.

In console I get error like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/js/library/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I configure resitfy to serve static files. I have tried  [this](https://gist.github.com/mcavage/1056404) solution but couldn't make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the `serveStatic` plug-in [described here](http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins).

Answer (score -2):

You didn't serve other static files such as: "js/library/jquery.js". I highly recommend using  [express framework](http://expressjs.com/) instead , it's easy for serving static files without doing it manually.

Comment: is it possible to use restify with express, I need restify to serve my xml

Comment: Restify isn't really meant to be run together with Express, not does it need to to serve static content.

Comment: @robertklep how can I run it then?

Comment: @robertklep for serveStatic plugin, what would be my path of static files,couldn't figure out with the example

Comment: @arnold try `directory: __dirname + '/../frontEnd'`

Answer (score -2):

What about having an Apache server for your static site? That way you won't have to write all through restify.

Just have your restify server to serve the xml you need (the way you are doing it), and have all your client-side html, css, js files in apache.